# How can I filter by image format on the dialog window when I upload an image in Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, image, format, odoo

I have a model with an image attribute:

```python
image = fields.Binary(
    string="Imagen",
    required=True
)
```

Inside the view a show it with:

```xml
<field name="image" widget="image" />
```

This open an operating system dialog window that allows me to select an image file. The problem is that I need to take only `*.jpg` files and I don't know how to open this dialog windows filtered with this kind of file.

Comment: With that version are you working? Check if my answer is useful, it works for the 8 version at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will decribe you all the procedure I had to do to find out what you should do. This could be useful for the next time you want to modify anything else:

### Inspection

If you inspect the html of the widget you can find the hidden input file:

```
<input accept="image/*" class="oe_form_binary_file" name="ufile" type="file">
```

So if you go to [**this w3schools**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) page you can check what `accept="image/*"` means. We must override it with `.jpg` or any other extension that you need.

### Find the Primary Source Code

Then you should look for the template on the original Odoo source code. As you can see in the `web` module the used template is the following:

```xml
<t t-name="HiddenInputFile">
    <div t-attf-class="oe_hidden_input_file #{fileupload_class or ''}" t-att-style="fileupload_style">
        <form class="oe_form_binary_form" t-att-target="fileupload_id"
            method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" t-att-action="fileupload_action || '/web/binary/upload'">
            <input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="" t-if="widget.session.override_session"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="callback" t-att-value="fileupload_id"/>
            <t t-raw="0"/>
            <input type="file" class="oe_form_binary_file" name="ufile" t-if="widget.widget!='image'"/>
            <input type="file" class="oe_form_binary_file" name="ufile" accept="image/*" t-if="widget.widget=='image'"/>
        </form>
        <iframe t-att-id="fileupload_id" t-att-name="fileupload_id" style="display: none"/>
    </div>
</t>
```

### Extend and Modify the Original Code

Finally you only need to override the input field with [**Qweb Template Inheritance**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/qweb.html#template-inheritance)

```xml
<templates id="image_widget_jpg_template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="HiddenInputFile">
        <t t-jquery="[accept='image/*']" t-operation="replace">
            <input type="file" class="oe_form_binary_file" name="ufile" accept=".jpg" t-if="widget.widget=='image'"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Comment: Just a contribution, supposily this worked in older versions, but I didn't check if it still works (the argument `filters` accepted regular expressions): `image = fields.Binary(string="Imagen", required=True, filters='*.jpg')`

Comment: filters='*.jpg' It does not work for me. I use google chrome and odoo14.

Comment: @forvas , Which version of odoo do you use?

Comment: @AkiraChen those days I had projects from 6.1 to 11 may be. That `filters` parameter for `Binary` fields doesn't work in Odoo 14.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution work for me.

py file

```
related_file1 = fields.Binary(string='1.FileName', attachment=True)
related_file_name1 = fields.Char(string='1.FileName')
```

xml file

```
<field name="related_file1" widget="binary" options="{'accepted_file_extensions': '.pdf,.jpg'}"]}" filename="related_file_name1"/>
<newline/>
<field name="related_file_name1" invisible="1"/>
```